# Mapping strings to integers in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, mapping

For building my Poker game, I abstract a "Hand" as a list of `card` objects.
For example, `['AC', '3D', '4S', 'KH', 'TC']` represents a `hand` object and each item of the list is a `card` object.

I want to rank the cards in a hand in descending order of their importance in the game.
i.e. `'A' > 'K' > ....(so on)... > '2'`

I am looking for mapping the rank of each card to a corresponding value.
For the above example, the correspondence will be `[14, 13, 10, 4, 3]`

I have the following functions to do this for me:

```
def mapper(ranks):
    mapping = {
            '2': 2,
            '3': 3,
            '4': 4,
            '5': 5,
            '6': 6,
            '7': 7,
            '8': 8,
            '9': 9,
            'T': 10,
            'J': 11,
            'Q': 12,
            'K': 13,
            'A': 14
        }
    new_ranks = [mapping[rank] for rank in ranks]
    return new_ranks

def card_ranks(cards):
    "Return a list of the ranks, sorted with higher first."
    ranks = [r for r,s in cards]
    return sorted(mapper(ranks), reverse=True)
```

These functions work fine but I don't find them enough Pythonic.
I would like to know how can I perform this mapping efficiently(maybe using `map` function).

Comment: [CodeReview.SE] might be a better place for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I find to be more readable and Pythonic

```
def card_ranks(cards):
    "Return a list of the ranks, sorted with higher first."
    ranks = ['--23456789TJQKA'.index(r) for r,s in cards]
    return ranks.sort(reverse=True)
```

Whenever we want to map a character to an `int`, we can use either of these techniques:

- Defining the mapping as `dict` and calling this map with the key values.
- Use of `index` on a String object. (as applicable in this case)

Moreover, if we want to map uppercase characters to their corresponding integer values in C, we can use something like this:

```
value_of_ch = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST'.index(ch + 65)
```